DB2 Index to cover JOIN, WHERE and GROUP BY
Does DB2 index cover JOIN, WHERE and GROUP BY columns. I have a query similar to below one which is not using the full index.
Query:
Select A.REF, A.MARKET, MAX(CREATE_TS) FROM ACTION A
INNER JOIN ACCESS AC ON A.ACC_ID = AC.ACC_ID AND AC.GROUP = 10 AND AC.PROF = 1
WHERE A.IND = 'MAND'
GROUP BY A.REF, A.MARKET

Index:
ON ACTION (ACC_ID, IND, REF, MARKET)
ON ACCESS (ACC_ID, GROUP, PROF)

Query is using index ACTION (ACCT_ID, IND) and ignoring the group by columns. It is using temp table for group by sorting.

Db2 cannot use the ACTION.REF or ACTION.MARKET columns for group-by, because they are not the first column of any index on ACTION (as per your question).  Assess a relevant index for group-by columns, or add a statistical-view , or add a column-group runstats on action(ref, market) to examine the impact of each change.

@mao If I change the Index to ACTION (REF, MARKET, ACC_ID, IND), will it use the index for group by, join and where?

No. I'm suggesting you assess an additional index, or if that is unsuitable (too costly to maintain) then assess one of the other suggestions. Db2 will only use an index if it is cost effective and index-column-order is relevant for requirements.

@mao which means we cannot have one index to cover join, where and group by. I know one index can cover both join and where. Also one index can cover both where and group by (without temporary table for group by). I will change the index to ACTION (REF, MARKET) and ACTION (ACC_ID, IND) and let DB2 decide which one to use. Thanks for your response.

I see no aggregate functions in the query. Why the GROUP BY?

updated the query to fetch max of create_ts to get the latest record's create time

The following indexes to optimize the query:
create index ix1 on action (ind, ref, market);

create index ix2 on access (group, prod, acc_id);

